# What is the bash equivalent to batchs' %*

Tags: bash, batch-file

If I have a batch file and want to just use all given script arguments I can use `%*`.

Example **a.bat**

```
echo %*
```

Calling `a.bat 1 2 3 4` gives:

```
1 2 3 4
```

how can I do the same in a bash script?

Comment: You can use `$*` in `bash`. If you have that question, you're inevitably going to have other questions on how to program a `bash` script. You should do some reading on `bash` script programming. Lots and lots of good info online if you search it: "bash script programming".

Comment: Another good reference (and my favorite BTW) is simply ```man bash```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"$*"` will return a single string with all the arguments separated by space.
`"$@"` will return N strings, one for each argument.

Example `a.sh`:

```
echo "$@"
```

Calling `a.sh 1 2 3 4` gives:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Another example of `a.sh`:

```
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Calling `a.sh  1 '2 2' '3 3 3' '4 4 4 4'` gives:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

As opposed to `a.sh` being:

```
printf "%s\n" "$*"
```

which will print:

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Just to point out: `"$@"` is almost always what you want; you rarely want to treat the arguments a single space-joined string.

Comment: And the quotes are crucial, otherwise each you'll get very different results.